# Evitar que desaparezca ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Buenas, Tengo una interfaz con 2 LinearLayout, uno debajo del otro. El superior, tiene un par de TextView y un Boton, Y el Inferior Tiene, Un ListView , debajo un TextView y 2 botones.

El tema es el siguiente: cuando hago click en los TextViews de mi Layout Superior, automaticamente aparece el teclado para escribir, empujando el Layout Inferior hacia arriba, ésto hace que los elementos que se encuentran en la parte inferior del ListView (items de la lista) no se visualicen, quedando solo los 2 superiores.

¿Como puedo Evitar ésto?

Necesito, que, en todo caso, si algo debe ocultarse, sean los Botones que están debajo del ListView (Los que están siendo empujados), pero la lista debe permanecer , en lo posible, Siempre Visible.

Mi Activity es el Siguiente:

```
    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal"> 

    [...] //Acá están Los TextViews y botones varios

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/sec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    //éste es el Listview del cual desaparecen los items inferiores

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lviewArtaGrabar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10pt"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10pt"
                    android:layout_weight="1" /> 

    // Y lo de aquí debajo, es lo que prefiero que se oculte

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                    android:layout_width="200pt"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Confirmar Inventario"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_complete"
                    android:layout_width="200pt"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Inventario Incompleto"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_force_close"
                    android:layout_width="200pt"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Forzar Inventario Completo"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Creo que no hace falta aclarar que todo está dentro de un RelativeLayout.
Estoy haciendo una app que únicamente se va a ejecutar en una tablet en modo Horizontal. O sea, que como se vea en otros dispositivos no importa mucho.

Comment: Sería buena idea agregar  el layout completo de tu Activity.

Comment: Eso es todo, faltaria la de abrir y cerrar el ReativeLayout que contiene a todo